# Github actions deployment suddenly hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, github-actions, github-pages

I have a personal website which uses github pages to host and deploy, https://github.com/tonydavis629/personal-site. It was working fine until yesterday when it suddenly started hanging on the Build and Deploy stage of my deployment. It will hang for hours until it says it is cancelled. Here is the output of the failed stage on the Actions tab on github

```
2h 22m 54s
Run git config user.name "Automated"

> personal-site@4.0.0 predeploy
> npm run build && react-snap


> personal-site@4.0.0 build
> rimraf ./build && react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx browserslist@latest --update-db
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx browserslist@latest --update-db
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  82.16 kB  build/static/js/main.7749ae65.js
  23.56 kB  build/static/js/872.f763e0ca.chunk.js
  7.79 kB   build/static/css/main.d4403bfe.css
  6.76 kB   build/static/js/166.f005bd44.chunk.js
  5.57 kB   build/static/js/964.46c409e0.chunk.js
  4.37 kB   build/static/js/209.d464d894.chunk.js
  4.23 kB   build/static/js/161.6a13cc1c.chunk.js
  3.12 kB   build/static/js/596.ad0d1198.chunk.js
  1.09 kB   build/static/js/453.436ed330.chunk.js
  765 B     build/static/js/478.1cd2f26a.chunk.js
  493 B     build/static/js/562.4dc7da4b.chunk.js
  400 B     build/static/js/922.fefd4601.chunk.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment

Error: The operation was canceled.
```

I notice that something changed in the Deployments / History page where suddenly it was being deployed by Github Actions 'on behalf' of me, instead of by me. Here is a picture of what I mean.

[image: Deployment History]

Since the last successful deployment the only thing I changed was adding some text, it seems clear that whatever is messed up is within gh-pages and not a build failure or anything like that. I'm not sure what to do, can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I've encountered frozen node GH workflows before. The default timeout is 6 hours, but it's pointless to wait that long - my own jobs will either work in minutes or hang, so I added this guard: `timeout-minutes: 15`  just under `runs-on:` to make it stop early. Unfortunately, that's just a bandaid on the wasted resources, it won't solve your actual problem. But I would recommend it anyway, because there really is no point is waiting 6 hours for GH's default timeout to kill your job.

Comment: Possible suggestion, have you considered using this action https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages to deploy?

Comment: @joanis I have added that timeout, thanks. I know basically nothing about github deployments, would I have to just modify my github-pages.yml "Build and Deploy" step with the "deploy" step from the deploy-pages action?

Comment: Yeah, basically. They do all the work for you that way. And it's better tested on their side.

Comment: @joanis I'm still struggling with this, tried the deploy-pages action but I'm pretty clueless about how github-pages works and I can't figure it out. I did try to npm install my website locally, but npm is throwing a bunch of vulnerabilities at me. I tried fixing it with npm audit fix and npm audit fix --force, but it reported even more vulnerabilities! Now I can't even build it locally. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that github's latest ubuntu was updated to 22.04. I reset it manually to ubuntu-20.04 in my github-pages.yml workflow and it fixed the problem. I'm sure there is a better solution but this is working for me now.